# set multiple parameter in recursive c#

Tags: c#, recursive-query

when I make 2 parameters. when the cursor on highlight ahref not getting value,  as the first parameter? but always get the value of its parent. 
What should I do with my code below: 
please help correct the errors / shortcomings of my code.

```
    private string LoadNavigasi(string kodeJabatan, ref int countLoop)
    {
        if (kodeJabatan == null)
            kodeJabatan = "001";

        DataSet ds = RunQuery("Select KodePosition,NamaPosition,Parent from Position where KodePosition = '" + kodeJabatan + "'");
        string temp = string.Empty;
        string tempP = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var kode = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            var nama = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
            var parent = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
            if (parent == "")
                parent = null;
            temp = string.Format("<a href=?Kode=" + kode + "&Name=" + nama + ">{0}</a>", nama);
            tempP = string.Empty;
            countLoop++;
            if (parent != null)
            {
                tempP = string.Format("{0}", LoadNavigasi(parent, ref countLoop));
                temp = string.Format("{1}<ul><li>{0}", temp, tempP);
            }
            else
            {
                temp = string.Format("{0}", temp);
            }
            return temp;
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Whats your code doing, whats not working, what does "cursor on highlight" mean?

Comment: "cursor on highlight" in my browser..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it helps but I simplify your code to what it's actually doing.

```
private string LoadNavigasi(string kodeJabatan)
{
    if (kodeJabatan == null)
        kodeJabatan = "001";

    DataSet ds = RunQuery("Select KodePosition,NamaPosition,Parent from Position where KodePosition = '" + kodeJabatan + "'");

    var kode = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
    var nama = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
    var parent = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();

    string temp = string.Format("<a href=?Kode={0}&Name={1}>{1}</a>", kode, nama);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent))
    {
        string tempP = LoadNavigasi(parent);
        temp = string.Format("{1}<ul><li>{0}", temp, tempP);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

You mention something about your second parameter in the line

```
temp = string.Format("<a href=?Kode=" + kode + "&Name=" + nama + ">{0}</a>", nama);
```

The second parameter is `nama` but I don't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: ups, sorry it does not work.the core of my question is, how to make a 2 href parameter from my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "make a 2 href parameter"?

Comment: "make a 2 href parameter"? => "Multiple Parameter in temp = string.Format("<a href=?Kode=" + kode + "&Name=" + nama + ">{0}</a>", nama); ???